# How to highlight the selected row in angular js 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

Hi i trying out an example like passing data from parent to child and child to parent by custom component.

Below are the files which i used for example.
i attached the both html and ts files of parent and child component.

each employee have button called select record. on click of button entire row should be highlighted.

```
     Parent component (app.component.ts)

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
        title = 'app';

    public employeeRecord: any = [
    {eId: 1, eName: "sachin", eCity: "Mumbai", eSalary: 8000},
    {eId: 2, eName: "Yuvi", eCity: "Panjab", eSalary: 9000},
    {eId: 3, eName: "Dhoni", eCity: "Ranchi", eSalary: 800},
    {eId: 4, eName: "Dravid", eCity: "Bangalore", eSalary: 8000},
    {eId: 5, eName: "Anil", eCity: "Delhi", eSalary: 2000}
];
selectedRecordData: any = {
    selectedEmplyoeeName: "",
    selectedEmplyoeeCity: "",
    selectedEmplyoeeSalary: ""
};
getSelectedRecord(data) {
    this.selectedRecordData = data;
}
}

Parent Component html (app.component.html)

    <h1>Employee Record List</h1>


      <h1>Selected Employee</h1>
       <h3>Id : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeId}}</h3>
       <h3>Name : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeName}}</h3>
       <h3>City : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeCity}}</h3>
       <h3>Salary : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeSalary}}</h3>

     <app-custom-component 
    [id] = "employee.eId" 
    [name] = "employee.eName"
    [city] = "employee.eCity"
    [salary] = "employee.eSalary"
     (sendRecord) = "getSelectedRecord($event)"
    *ngFor="let employee of employeeRecord;">
     </app-custom-component>

custom-component (Custom-component.ts).
   import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
     '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-custom-component',
       templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.css']
   })
     export class CustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
isSelect: false;    
@Input('id') employeeId: number;
@Input('name') employeeName: string;
@Input('city') employeeCity: string;
@Input('salary') employeeSalary: number;

@Output() sendRecord: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public selectedRecord(event) {
    let selectedEmplyoeeRecordDetails: any = {
        selectedEmplyoeeId: this.employeeId,
        selectedEmplyoeeName: this.employeeName,
        selectedEmplyoeeCity: this.employeeCity,
        selectedEmplyoeeSalary: this.employeeSalary,
    };
    this.sendRecord.emit(selectedEmplyoeeRecordDetails);
      isSelect = true;
     }
   }



 **Custom component (custom.component.html)**
<div [ngClass]="{'highlight': isSelect}">
<h3>Id : {{employeeId}}</h3>
<h3>Name : {{employeeName}}</h3>
<h3>City : {{employeeCity}}</h3>
<h3>Salary : {{employeeSalary}}</h3>
<button (click)= "selectedRecord(event)">SelectRecord</button>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class say 'highlight' and apply it only when selected employee matches with the component's employee. So with modification you custom component should look like this:

***Custom-component.ts***

```
export class CustomComponentComponent implements OnInit {

@Input('selected') isSelected:boolean;
@Input('name') employeeName: string;
@Input('city') employeeCity: string;
@Input('salary') employeeSalary: number;

@Output() sendRecord: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
count: number = 0;
public selectedRecord(event) {
    let selectedEmplyoeeRecordDetails: any = {
        selectedEmplyoeeName: this.employeeName,
        selectedEmplyoeeCity: this.employeeCity,
        selectedEmplyoeeSalary: this.employeeSalary,
};
this.sendRecord.emit(selectedEmplyoeeRecordDetails);
}

}
```

***custom-component.html***

```
<div [ngClass]="{'highlight': isSelected}">
 <h3>Name : {{employeeName}}</h3>
 <h3>City : {{employeeCity}}</h3>
 <h3>Salary : {{employeeSalary}}</h3>
 <button (click)= "selectedRecord(event)" >SelectRecord</button>
 </div>
<hr>
```

and finally ***app.component.html***

```
<h1>Employee Record List</h1>

<hr>

    <h1>Selected Employee</h1>
    <h3>Name : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeName}}</h3>
    <h3>City : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeCity}}</h3>
    <h3>Salary : {{selectedRecordData.selectedEmplyoeeSalary}}</h3>
    <hr>
    <app-custom-component 
    [name] = "employee.eName"
    [selected]= "selectedRecordData.id === employee.id"
    [city] = "employee.eCity"
    [salary] = "employee.eSalary"
    (sendRecord) = "getSelectedRecord($event)"
    *ngFor="let employee of employeeRecord;">
    </app-custom-component>
```

I have added an extra property `id` as unique identifier.

Comment: It is not working. I added unique employee Id for each employee.                    where can i write [ngStyle] attribute ?

Comment: Check my answer. I have used ngstyle in custom component. And can you update your question with the code you tried.

Comment: I updated the code please can you check and verify it.